# Kentico v9 - Can't edit form after migration to staging server

Tags: kentico

My dev server seems fine, i can access all the sub levels with the form (Recorded Data, General, etc.). My staging site only has Alternative Forms and Versions.

I thought something may have gone wrong with the migration and manual sync tasks, but I attempted to create a new form in staging, the result is the same.

I went back to the documentation to see if I missed a step when I attempted to create a new form, but nothing is mentioned. Is there a site or setting flag i missed?

Comment: Have you checked your user permissions and UI personalization on the stage server? Sounds like an issue there perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a multitude of issues which are causing this but first things I'd check are:

- Check your Kentico event log for errors/warnings
- Check the server event log for errors/warnings
- Ensure all your files are copied from dev to staging server(s)
- When you moved from dev to staging, did you [resign your macros](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Working+with+macro+signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros)?
- Did you clear your cache on the staging server and in your browser(s)

I'm guessing it is an issue with cache but the others should also be reviewed, especially resigning the macros.

Comment: Looks like it's the macro's. I cleared the event log, went to edit the form and have MacroResolver errors. Though the form isn't using any macros, but it's a start.

Comment: The fact that the form itself isn't using any macros is irrelevant.  The fact that the UI is using macros is the part in which you're having problems with.  Resigning those macros, will resolve the issue then.